# Extjs issue with Spring boot Rest Api

Tags: html, spring-boot, iframe, extjs

I have been working on converting a simple MVC application into Spring Boot Application with ExtJs as front end.
Facing issue with ExtJs inside xeditor iframe and Spring boot Rest Api

Error below:

xeditor_core.min.js:formatted:2:8698 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'QuickTips')

xeditor_core.min.js:formatted:2:10701 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')

Code :

1]            this.iframeDocumentBody.appendChild(this.iframeEditorContentContainer),

2]            this.iframeBody.appendChild(this.iframeDocumentBody),

3]            this.iframeWin.Ext.QuickTips.init(),

Here the Ext Object at line 3] is NUll , However in the original MVC application this object is present.

4]           this.iframeEl = Ext.get(this.editor.iframe),

5]            this.iframeWin = this.editor.iframe.contentWindow,

at line 4] the EXt object is present not present in contentWindow object in line 5].

Both the old MVC and the Spring boot Rest Api give the same response .

can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue in your `static/iframe.html` file. Make sure that the following line is included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/extjs/all.js"></script>
```

This will inject ExtJS into the iframe and include the `Ext` namespace there, so `Ext.QuickTips` should be available again.

In addition, the Developer Network Panel should be used to ensure that the file can be loaded successfully.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it did not solve the issue

Comment: Can you make sure that the "all.js" is successfully loaded twice in your Network Panel? (F12 -> Network -> Reload Page -> Search for "all.js"). Are you sure the iframe.html will be loaded correctly? It could be possible that you also have to adjust the "iframeURL" setting in your "attributes.js" file.